# Align to left button with Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using a Bootstrap 3 in my application where I have select input with some options. There is a small problem when I'm trying align this select to left. Select is not aligned to left when I'm adding class:

```
class="col-md-8 pull-left"
```

or

```
class="col-md-8 text-left">
```

in div. Below I show screen from application and my code:

[image]

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="row spacer-top-3">
  <label class="form-check-label">
            Send survey for client:
        </label>
  <input id="checkbox" ng-model="sendSurvey" type="checkbox" ng-change="checkSendSurvey()" class="trans-pro-checkbox">
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <select class="form-control" id="type_upload" ng-show="sendSurveyChecked">
                <option value="<% 1 %>"> Uploaded file</option>
                <option value="<% 2 %>">Shared folder</option>
            </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

How coul I align that to left correctly? I would be greateful for help

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle for your code?

Comment: columns 15x left-right padding and rows have -15px. The space you see left to the select is padding of column div I think, and you don't have column in your checkbox div

Answer (score 0):

Your `select` needs to set to certain width so try a fixed width or `fit-content` if not for IE or Edge.

```css
.control-width {
  max-width: 200px;
  //max-width:fit-content    Not in IE or Edge
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class="row spacer-top-3">
    <label class="form-check-label">
            Send survey for client:
        </label>
    <input id="checkbox" ng-model="sendSurvey" type="checkbox" ng-change="checkSendSurvey()" class="trans-pro-checkbox">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <select class="form-control control-width" id="type_upload" ng-show="sendSurveyChecked">
                <option value="<% 1 %>"> Uploaded file</option>
                <option value="<% 2 %>">Shared folder</option>
            </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```